# Permission denied in fish shell on Debian when I edited the oh-my-fish "theme" file

Tags: debian, fish, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I edited the "theme" file to display "bobthefish" instead of "default" using Windows.

```
<W> fish: An error occurred while redirecting file “/home/purplesci/.config/omf/theme”
open: Permission denied
```

This is what the fish console in WSL displays now when I open it. How can I get rid of that?

Answer (score 1):

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2016/06/15/wsl-file-system-support/

You should not mess with files under VolFS using Windows. 
To repair this file you can move it under some other directory, e.g. C:\Temp. Then you can move that file back using WSL:

```
mv /mnt/c/Temp/theme /home/purplesci/.config/omf/theme
```

Comment: It says `mv: replace '/home/purplesci/.config/omf/theme', overriding mode 0000 (---------)?` What should I type?

Comment: Try to delete that file from windows